# How to remove extra space from mui Grid Data Table , when scrollbar appers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, scrollbar

I am using the mui data grid, the problem I am facing with it when the ScrollBar appears the table header is also taking some space, I want the row to only take space.

Below is my code, Here I am giving some inline style to DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid
  disableRowSelectionOnClick
   style={{
     maxHeight: `calc(100vh - ${HEADER_HEIGHT + 24 + 92 + 40}px)`,
     overflowY: "auto",
     scrollBehavior: "smooth",
   }}

  sx={{
    "& .super-app-theme--header": {
      background: "#F1F5F9",
      paddingLeft: "24px",
      fontSize: "12px",
      fontWeight: "500",
      letterSpacing: "0.05em",
      color: "#6b778c",
    },
    "&.MuiDataGrid-root": {
      borderRadius: "0px",
      borderBottomLeftRadius: "6px",
      borderBottomRightRadius: "6px",
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus": {
      outline: "none",
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
      paddingLeft: "24px",
    },
  }}
  rows={fetchIndustryQuery.data.map((industryData) => ({
    id: industryData.industry.id,
    name: industryData.industry.name,
    createdBy: industryData.creatorName,
    createdById: industryData.industry.createdBy,
  }))}
  columns={industryColumns}
  loading={fetchIndustryQuery.isLoading}
  initialState={{
    pagination: {
      paginationModel: {
        pageSize: 10,
      },
    },
  }}
  pageSizeOptions={[10]}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, can you share a screenshot of the problem?